# logrotate logs in special dir format

Tags: fedora, logrotate

I have my log file in this format in /var/log//YYYYMMDD/app[1-5].log

I would like the following:

On the 3rd of each month, move the directory /var/log//YYYYMMDD where MM is the previous month to /var/log//YYYY/MM and compress either it or its content log files.

Comment: You don't want `YYYY` to be the previous year if the previous month is `12`?

Comment: yes correct, previous year

Comment: can logrotate help or do I do it myself with a cron shell job?

Comment: I don't think that you can do this with logrotate, The `dateformat`  applies to `dateext` but I am not sure, you can have directory separators in that format and have logrotate create the directories. I would just use logrotate (if you already do) for the rotation and compression, and use cron to start a script on the 3rd to make the directory and move the logs (and use compressions from the script if you don't run logrotate at all).